# Issues with implementing apply.weekly function

Tags: r, date, filter, shiny, apply

I am currently filtering some data to be plotted and have decided to use the apply.weekly function to show the weekly mean of a variable (weight) for a group of people over a period of time.
I think my code is very close to correct. When I run the code, I get the following error "Error in FUN: object 'Date' not found"

I have provided a small bit of the relevant code. Any help would be great!!

'''

```
ui <- dashboardPage(

checkboxGroupInput("Teaminput", "Select Team", c("Team 1", "Team 2"), selected ="Team 1"),
selectInput( "Category", "Select Category", c("Overview", "Position", "Age", "Player"))

plotOutput("Plot1"))





server <- function(session, input, output) {
          
 output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
  
  filtered_data1 <- filter(df, Date >= format(input$daterange[1]) & Date <= format(input$daterange[2])) %>% 
                    filter(Team %in% input$Teaminput)
  
  if (input$Category == "Overview") {
    dfavg1 <- xts(df$Weight, as.Date(df$Date))
    variable_df1 <- apply.weekly(dfavg1, mean)
  }

  ggplot(variable_df1, aes(x= Date, y = Weight))
  
  })
  }
```

Here is the packages loaded:

library (dplyr)
library(shiny)
library (shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(readr)
library(plotly)
library(xts)

Comment: Can you please add the loaded packages? It could be the case that `filter` is used from a different package than `dplyr`

Comment: Yes absolutely! Thank you for your reply. I will edit the post